# How to change specific img src when button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I have this piece of code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button.check").on("click", function(event) {
            var serv_id = event.currentTarget.id;
            $.post("/check", {serv_id: serv_id }).done(function(result3){
                $("button#"+serv_id).hasClass("paid")
                $("img#img"+serv_id).attr("src", "/static/check.png");
                $("img.this_img").each(function(){
                    if($(this).hasClass("paid")){
                        $(this).attr("src", "/static/check.png");
                        }
                 });
                });
               });
              });
```

[image]

And here is HTML:

```
<td>
    <img id="{{ status }}" class="this_img {{ sid }}" src="/static/notcheck.png" width="21">
    &nbsp;
    <button id="{{ sid }}" type="button" class="{{ status }} check btn btn-primary btn-xs">Paid</button>
</td>
```

So what I want is the button I want the img src of "X" to be changed permanently.

-I'm using Flask.
 -When the button is clicked it updates column "status" from the database from "unpaid" to "paid".So the button class changes from "unpaid" to "paid.but I can't figure it out how to change the img src after that.
 -Thanks in advance!

Updated code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button.check").on("click", function(event) {
            var serv_id = event.currentTarget.id;
            $.post("/check", {serv_id: serv_id }).done(function(result3){
                $("button#"+serv_id).hasClass("paid")
                $("img#img"+serv_id).attr("src", "/static/check.png");
             });
            });
             $("img").each(function(){
                  if($(this).hasClass("paid")){
                    $(this).attr("src", "/static/check.png");
                   }
                });
            });
```

And HTML:

```
        <td>
           <img id="img{{ sid }}" class="this_img {{ status }}"  src="/static/notcheck.png" width="21">
           &nbsp;
           <button id="{{ sid }}" type="button" class="{{ status }} check  btn btn-primary btn-xs">
           Paid
           </button>
        </td>
```

Comment: are you sure `serv_id` in your js is same as `{{ status }}` in your html?

Comment: Yes I can print that here.

Comment: serv_id  has nothing to do with {{ status }} , serv_id is the id from database ,printed here as {{ sid }}

Comment: You are giving your image this id : `img id="{{ status }}"` and you are selecting by this id : `serv_id`. So if they are different your img element will not be selected by this : `$("img#"+serv_id)`.

Comment: Maybe you should have something like this : img id="{{ sid }}"

Comment: You were right,I did what you said,but still nothing,it's just changeing button's class from 'unpaid' to 'paid'.but the img doesn't change.

Comment: Make sure id of button and image are different, because if you do `img id="{{ sid }}" ` and `button id="{{ sid }}"` then it will be same. Try doing `img id="img{{ sid }}" ` and select like : `$("img#img" + serv_id)`

Comment: I did what you said,img still not changing.What could I possibly do wrong?I'm on working on this issue for 2 days straight.

Comment: Post your updated code in the end of the question

Comment: Shouldnt `$("button#serv_id")` be `$("button#"+serv_id)`?

Comment: Yes,I did how you said and now the img changes but not permanent,it comes back to "X" even if there is no refresh on the page.So the cycle is "NOT CHECK" - Button pressed - "CHECK" -> "NOT CHECK".

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle of the code?

Comment: When you click the button what is the value of  {{status}}. Try to console log it

Comment: Is first time when I use jsfiddle, sorry if not correct. https://jsfiddle.net/tiptoettt/3zxgygxp/

Comment: Before I click the button:             <button id="177" type="button" class="unpaid check btn btn-primary btn-xs">Paid</button> And after I click the button:             <button id="177" type="button" class="paid check btn btn-primary btn-xs">Paid</button>

Comment: I solved it partially,is just that the img change is not permanent,after refresh it goes back to normal.Check updated code please!

Comment: Where are you changing the class of button from unpaid to paid?

Comment: In mysql I have a column 'status' wich by default inserts 'unpaid' record. After you click the button, that record updates to 'paid'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion in the comments. The answer is driven by your following two comments :

> ...is just that the img change is not permanent,after refresh it goes
>   back to normal....

and

> In mysql I have a column 'status' wich by default inserts 'unpaid'
>   record. After you click the button, that record updates to 'paid'.

So basically your records are getting updated and also when u update the record to paid you update the image source, but you do no update the image source when rendering the html based on the button status. You are always putting unpaid image source.

Do something like this :

Add `status` class to the image as well

```
<td>
    <img id="img{{ sid }}" class="this_img {{ status }}" src="/static/notcheck.png" width="21">
    &nbsp;
    <button id="{{ sid }}" type="button" class="{{ status }} check btn btn-primary btn-xs">
         Paid
    </button>
</td>
```

Then in the `document.ready`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //...
    //Your updated/working code, that you have mentioned in the question
    //...

    //Add the following:
    $("img").each(function(){
           console.log($(this).attr("class");
           if($(this).hasClass("paid")){
                  $(this).attr("src", "/static/check.png");
           }
    });

});
```

---

#### UPDATE

---

You could do one hack.

Rename your images to `paid.png` and `unpaid.png`

And then change your code to this :

`src="/static/{{status}}.png"`

```
 <td>
     <img id="img{{ sid }}" class="this_img {{ status }}"  src="/static/{{status}}.png" width="21">
       &nbsp;
       <button id="{{ sid }}" type="button" class="{{ status }} check  btn btn-primary btn-xs">
       Paid
       </button>
    </td>
```

I know it is not a proper solution but to get you through.

Comment: Still after refresh the image goes back to "notcheck.png",maybe I need to make an jinja if stateament,I don't know I tried different ways,nothing worked.

Comment: when you refresh does the image have `paid` class?

Comment: Yes,it does,cause the change is in db and the class is the object in jinja.

Comment: You will have to write a if case, if the class is paid then src of image should be check else uncheck when rendering html only

Comment: Yes I know that,but the problem is I don't know how to do that.Because I tried something in different variants and nothing worked how it should work.

Comment: The code that i told you to add, is that running? did you check that? maybe console log? Check updated console log added

Comment: I told you,is not working at all.Is a a bit tricky, the image changes after the button is clicked,the 'status' changes to paid,but after refresh the image goes back to notcheck

Comment: My updated code does not console log anything??? I have added a logging statement

Comment: Ok,I made some adjustments, it logs this:  "this_img unpaid".And after button is pressed it logs "this_img paid".

Comment: I have just noticed that if I reclick the button wtih 'paid' class after refresh,all the images with 'paid' changes  src to 'check'.

Comment: Ok,I solved this ,I will update the code,with just one amendment -  if I refresh, for just a fraction of second it shows the 'notcheck' image.You have any idea?

Comment: If it is logging `this_img unpaid` for all the images that means status is not getting set to paid on document load. You have to write the code and execute it when the status is set

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help.This really solved my issue.